# How to implement a cron job for every minute and every 5 minutes?

Tags: 8, cron

In D8 I programmed hook_cron. I tested it several times but I cannot see any log in the watchlog.

The name of the module is nncbt. The code is placed in nncbt.module.

Any suggestions what I should do?

```
function nncbt_cron() {  


    $last_run_per_minut = \Drupal::state()->get('nncbt.last_run', 0);
    // If 1 minutes passed since last time.
    if ((REQUEST_TIME - $last_run_per_minut) > 60) {

        \Drupal::logger('nncbt')->info('Runnning Cron every 1 minut log');

        // Update last run.
        \Drupal::state()->set('nncbt.last_run', REQUEST_TIME);

    }   

    // Run the following every 5 minutes
    $last_run_per_5_minuts = \Drupal::state()->get('nncbt.last_run_5_minuts', 0);

    // If 5 minutes passed since last time.
    if ((REQUEST_TIME - $last_run_per_5_minuts) > 300) {

        \Drupal::logger('nncbt')->info("Runnning Cron every 5 minut log");


        // Update last run.
        \Drupal::state()->set('nncbt.last_run_5_minuts', REQUEST_TIME);

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you running cron?

Comment: Inside, by clicking admin menu> run cron. Also tried the button "Run Cron" on url admin/config/system/cron.

Comment: Did you rebuild the caches after adding your hook? Is cron completing? Check the status page, cron last run X ago.

Comment: If I run the function nncbt_cron() throught developers, execute php code everything is working fine.

Comment: Then it sounds like drupal doesn't know about your hook. Rebuild the caches.

Comment: Rebuild caches already 10 times but no luck in that :-(

Comment: You most likely mean `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_cron/8.6.x)

> The engine will then **call the hook whenever a cron run happens**, as
>   defined by the administrator.

In other words, hook_cron gets executed **after** a cron run happens. So if you have cron set to run once a day, then your hook_cron script only gets executed once per day. So you need to set cron to run every 5 minutes or less.

A better alternative, I suggest you use a module like [Ultimate   Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) which allows you to schedule different cron run times for different cron tasks. This way, cron doesn't run every single task every 5 minutes and instead it runs your specific task only.

Comment: Even if Drupal's cron runs every 5 minutes there is little additional overhead as tasks are (or should be using state API) scheduled independently of cron running. Having cron run more regularly is desirable; if it only runs once a day then ALL cron tasks are going to run at once, adding to overhead. (assuming you don't have badly written cron tasks that is)

Comment: @Duncanmoo which is why I mentioned about using [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) in my answer, so you can run specific cron tasks and different times.

Comment: Totally, and to confirm that Ultimate cron is the solution to granular control over Drupal's cron (even though its 8 version is in alpha), its interface and options are a bit daunting but it really gives you control.